# Wildfly static store content protection

Tags: wildfly

I am using wildfly and I create a folder to store images. eg:

localhost:8080/images/1/3487722873453756755.jpeg

but if i put :

localhost:8080/images/1/

our

localhost:8080/images/

I can see all files in that folders

How can I protect that folders?

My standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <location name="/images" handler="PicturesDir"/> 
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            <file name="PicturesDir" path="C:\Users\diogo\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin\Images\" directory-listing="true"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: I want to serve just a picture

Comment: Who are you protecting it from?

Comment: what kind of protection do you need?

Comment: try configuring Apache HTTPD server infront of Wildfly server.